# How do I make a tooltip point at a specific label in C#?

Tags: c#, tooltip, balloon-tip

In my application I want to use a tooltip to point at a label to get the users attention:

```
toolTip.IsBalloon = true;
toolTip.Show("message", label1);
```

The problem is that the balloon isn't pointing at the specified label.
What should I do?

Comment: And the most interesting question: what is ToolTip class? BCL, or third-party?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known bug.

Try calling it twice for a hack work-around:

```
toolTip.Show(string.Empty, label1, 0);
toolTip.Show("message", label1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.. more specific (i.e) how much time the tool tip will be displayed...

When MouseLeave

```
   public class MouseLeave
   {
       public void mouseLeave(Label label1, ToolTip ttpTemp)
       {
          ttpTemp.Hide(label1);
       }
  }
```

when mouse enter

```
  public class MouseOver
  {
    public void mouseOver(Label label1, ToolTip ttpTemp)
    {
                    ttpTemp.AutoPopDelay = 2000;
                    ttpTemp.InitialDelay = 1000;
                    ttpTemp.ReshowDelay = 500;
                    ttpTemp.IsBalloon = true;
                    ttpTemp.SetToolTip(label1, "Message1");
                    ttpTemp.Show("message1", label1,label1.width,label1.height/10,5000);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Mouse enter or leave doesn't fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Tooltip works with MouseHover and MouseLeft [just imagine in this way]
If the mouse come over the Label, the tooltip will be displayed, when the mouse left, tooltip will dissappear.

and the code should be:

```
    ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
    t.IsBalloon = true;
    t.ToolTipTitle = "Title";
    t.SetToolTip(label1, "Text");
```

just ToolTipTitle is optional :)