# Winforms Balloon Tooltip not working

Tags: c#, winforms

Would anyone know how/why specifying a `ToolTip` control' property called `IsBalloon` to `true` would cause the tooltips to simply never show at all?

Must there be other properties set to go along with it for it to show up?

It just never shows a tooltip ever... This isn't the known bug of "After a couple of times it stops working".

Comment: If `IsBalloon` is set to `false`, does it show rectangular tooltip all the time?

Comment: Yes! it does! that's the weird thing.

Comment: Does this help? Supposedly there is a bug and have to call Show twice.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627185/how-do-i-make-a-tooltip-point-at-a-specific-label-in-c/7627228#7627228

Comment: tried that one too... doesn't do anything :(